# How to make a delay timer in vb

Tags: .net

I wanna know about how to make delay in my Tic tac toe game.
I want to make a delay between turns of two players.

When player one make 'X',i want 3 seconds delay before second player make 'O'.

Thats all.
Please help me with it...

P.s i am juz a beginner.

Comment: Welcome to STO ! without asking for opinions and code helps, you need to provide what you have tried out. As a new bee, please read the STO guide on how ask a proper question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this can be done with many ways.. You must explain a little bit more detailed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you do not provide a code, it will be difficult. But anyway, use a normal timer. You can do it by entering the designer, in Toolbox choosing "Timer" and then double-click. It will generate an event called

```
Timer1_Tick...

End Sub
```

In that Sub you write "Timer1.Stop". You can then set the Interval of the timer in the designer to 3000 (means 3 seconds).
Now you have something like this

```
Timer1_Tick...
    Timer1.Stop()
    OtherPlayersTurn()
End Sub
```

And now instead of calling "OtherPlayersTurn()" directly, you call "Timer1.Start()".
It will delay 3 seconds without blocking the program.